# How to get the raw markup from a jquery mobile pageload request?

Tags: ajax, jquery-mobile, pageload

How can you get the raw HTML markup from an AJAX request that loads a page in jquery mobile?

My page has a menu outside of the page container element (data-role="page") and I need to update it on each page load but jquery-mobile only gives me the page markup from the request not the entire document.

I've even tried using the global ajaxSuccess callback for jquery; apparently jquery-mobile feels the need to filter this to just the page element also.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just assign an id to the menu page and access it directly?

```
$('#myMenu').html(newContent);
```

Comment: That would work if I could get the value for newContent but because it's outside of the page element jquery-mobile is loading I can't seem to read it from the markup returned in the ajax request.

Comment: What event are you listening on?  I think pagebeforeload gives you access to both pages. Do you have some sample code to post?

Comment: I've inspected the objects provided by the pagebeforeload, pageload, pagechange, and pagebeforechange events and not found anything that can give me the markup I want. I've also tried the global ajax hook for jquery (ajaxComplete and ajaxSuccess). My HTML code is similar to this: [link](http://privatepaste.com/4a0857e7d9). I need to get the contents of #menu.

Answer (score 0):

Found the http request object in the pageload event.

```
$(document).bind("pageload", function (e, data) {
    console.log(data.xhr.responseText);
});
```